# How to get data from JSON using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('emp', ['$scope', 'empService', function($scope, empService){
    $scope.doSearch = function(){
        empService.findEmployeeById($scope.searchempno, function(r){
            $scope.empno = r.empno;
            $scope.ename = r.ename;
            $scope.salary = r.salary;
            $scope.dptno = r.dptno;
        });
    };
}]);

app.service('empService', ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log){
    this.findEmployeeById = function(empno, cb){
        $http({
            url: 'employees.json' + empno,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(resp){
            cb(resp.data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="emp">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Enter Employee Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchEmpno"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSearch()">Search</button>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">Employee No</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">{{empno}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">Employee Name</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">{{ename}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">Salary</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">{{salary}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">Deptno</div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">{{dptno}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I gave the number in input field like 1001 and click the search button. It will not show the details. I have checked the console, there is no error. My JSON file has been placed the same location of the HTML file.

Thanks,
SamBhishma

Comment: Usually you would need to parse the response as json by doing reap.json()

Comment: Also is there any reason you're mixing promises and callbacks? You could return the value and use findEmployeeById().then(function(data)) {

Comment: No reasons. I want to display the details of the JSON. Could you please change the code? here is my JSON[
    {
        "empno": 1001,
        "ename": "allu",
        "salary": 40000,
        "dptno": 206
    },
    {
        "empno": 1002,
        "ename": "sam",
        "salary": 30000,
        "dptno": 205
    },
    {
        "empno": 1003,
        "ename": "Nasa",
        "salary": 30000,
        "dptno": 207
    },
    {
        "empno": 1004,
        "ename": "sam",
        "salary": 47000,
        "dptno": 203
    }

]

Comment: can u create a plunker? I'll fix the issue.

Comment: Here is the plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/tPb0Rf5C8GSSZgGX0ZMR?p=preview

Comment: one obvious problem is you have used different case for searchempno in view and controller.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an updated plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4QCcEsmrRMHLpdwScmjQ?p=preview). First issue was what I mentioned in the comment. In your view, you are writing `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchEmpno"/>`and in your controller, you're trying to access this variable as `searchempno`

Second issue is in your http request. You cannot pick and choose the data from json file based on the id. You have to get the entire JSON file, parse it and filter out the value if it matches your `searchEmpno` model value. I fixed it in the plunker.

Third [issue](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot), you are attaching plain values to your scope like `$scope.empno` , `$scope.ename`. Instead, you need to put such values into an object, so in your controller, put the matched employee object in the scope and in your view, reference it as `{{obj.ename}}` and so on.

Another thing, no need to return callbacks inside then. The clean way of handling successful, failed http calls is:

```
$http.get('url').then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Read more about them [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Take a look at the updated plunker to see if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your model variable is wrong inside the view, try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchEmpno"/>
```

[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/N6XDk5OyJ6qjvjCxGMUt?p=preview)

Comment: that's not the only problem here, this will not make the code work

Comment: @clever_bassi probably he needs to implement the logic to query

Comment: In my understanding, he cannot just filter out the response by appending the id to the url while doing the get request.

Comment: Yes you are right , either he needs to fetch all the data initially or he has to implement on the server side